# ionic 5 open modal in full screen without changing other modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Is it possible to open a particular modal in full screen without affecting other modals. I can apply the style to modal-wrapper in global.scss but that applies to all the modals in app which is not what I want. I only need to open two or three modals into full-screen rest needs to stay in default size.

It's not an issue on a small screen as it's by default full screen on the small screen but on a bigger screen, they are not full screen.

Here's my code sample

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-modal-ehedzz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Thanks

Comment: Put your specific classes into global.scss

Answer (score 3):

Just in case if someone else having same issue, just add this in global.scss

```
 .fullscreen {
      --width:100% !important;
      --height:100% !important;
  }

 const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: NewModalPage,
      cssClass: 'fullscreen'
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Put your style for custom classes into global.scss. Like this:

```
.dialog-fullscreen .modal-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

`dialog-fullscreen` is `my-custom-class` in your code

Comment: didn't work but got idea that solved issue